# How can block an external user from viewing a list on users in my company in AAD?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

let's suppose I created a used in AAD and I would like this user to be not able to view users that are already in AAD. basically I want to isolate this user from other users so its just a loan user.
I have made a group where this user will be stored but this is pretty much everything I did at this point.

Answer (score 1):

You can restrict access to the Azure AD portal to only allow administrator users, but this is a global setting. After enabling this setting, all users will need any administrator role assigned to view the Azure AD directory, the least privileged role would be **Directory readers**.

See [Restrict member users' default permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/users-default-permissions#restrict-member-users-default-permissions)

For external guest users, you can set the setting **Guest user access restrictions** to `Restricted access`. This is another global setting.

See [Restrict guest access permissions in Azure Active Directory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/enterprise-users/users-restrict-guest-permissions)

Comment: wont be a good option for me, i have around 300 people :(, maybe create a separate tenant ?

Comment: @daily_vlad_two I think you have to ask yourself, why would all 300 users also need directory access? And for those that actually do, you could easily assign the Directory Reader role to all 300 users with a simple PowerShell script.